# SAS: export the data to the particular range of Excel file

Tags: sas

Do you know please some method to export the data to the particular range of Excel file?
The proc export doesn’t work with range statement.
I would like to export the data and then to recalculate it with the Excel formulas.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Appears to be a repeat of the question [Exporting sas dataset to excel named ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578013/exporting-sas-dataset-to-excel-named-ranges)

Comment: What makes you think you cannot export to a range?

Comment: Thank you, Richard, this solution doesn't work for me, SAS didn't recognise the range, I don't know why.

Comment: @Reeza I triyed this code, it doesn't work:

Comment: data toto;
input X1 X2;
cards; 
10 10
;
run;

Proc Export Data=toto
 Outfile= "\\laxxx.com\LMPAPROD\USINE_PRIIPS\5. RETRAITEMENTS MANUELS\Chaine Profils\4. Analyse\Marie_TEST\Class_test.xlsx"
 dbms=xlsx
  replace;
 sheet=Class_test;
 Range='Class_test$D2:E2';
quit;

Comment: You only need to use one of SHEET or RANGE not both and what did you get in the log? And please paste your code into your question by editing it.

Comment: My apologies, XLSX does not support RANGES unfortunately. Are you exporting to a file that already exists or a new file? If a new file perhaps you can use ODS EXCEL? Otherwise you can try PCFILES engine or DDE/VB.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Does it work for xlsm?